# How do i use getopts to avoid running a script when there is no parameter entered?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Here is what I'm attempting to do

```
while getopts "h?rd" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        echo "invalid"
        exit 0
        ;;
    r)  report=1
        ;;
    d)  delete=1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

-r & -d work, also any other character passed as a parameter sends out an error.
but if I dont use a parameter, the code runs too. I want an error to be prompted then as well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, [\[ this \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50564/25919)  & [\[ this \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55762/25919) should solve your problem.

Comment: I wanted to know what should the value for an invalid argument be, in the **case** section.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$#` variable of bash to find no arguments. Also other invalid arguments can be obtained by using `case *)` in `getopts`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "no arguments"
  exit 1
fi
while getopts ":h\?rd" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|"\?")
        echo "valid"
        exit 0
        ;;
    r)  report=1
        ;;
    d)  delete=1
        ;;
    *)  echo "not valid"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Actually, you can use `\?)` to detect invalid options (if `getopts` doesn't recognize the option, it returns `?`).

Comment: ++, but but to promote good habits I suggest outputting error message to _stderr_.

Answer (score 0):

> but if I dont use a parameter, the code runs too.

getopts can't help you with this. You may put

```
if [ -z "$@" ]
then
echo "No arguments entered.. >&2
echo "Usage command -[h|?|r|]" >&2
exit 1 
fi
```

in the beginning to deal with this situation.

Also I would suggest some minor changes to the script as below :

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":hr:d" opt; do
#adding a colon in the beginning of the optstring supresses the
#system generated error message for invalid options.
    case "$opt" in
    h)
        echo "Help Stuff"
        ;;
    r)  report=1
        echo $report
        ;;
    d)  delete=1
        echo $delete
        ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option $OPTARG"
        echo "Aborting.."
        exit 1 >&2 # Once an invalid option found abort
    esac
done
shift # Checking for non-option arguments.
[[ $1 = "--" ]] && shift #Non option arguments begin with a --, So you need to 'shift' once more
lastparams=("$@")
echo "${lastparams[@]}"
```

**Note**

The standard file desctiptors are 0(stdin), 1(stdout) and 2(stderr).
You may replace `&2` with `/dev/stderr`.